# pointer to 2d array confusion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For my comprehension of pointers and arrays, if I have 2d array like this:

```
int arr[3][4];
```

Should i need to reference this array using a pointer, I need to declare the pointer like this:

```
int (*ptr)[4];
ptr = arr;
```

or

```
int (*(*ptr)[3])[4];
ptr = &arr;
```

The second approach gives this warning

```
initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

I need to know why.
Thanks

Comment: A pointer to `arr` (the type given by `&arr`) have the type `int (*)[3][4]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes the warning is gone

Comment: Note, that if you intend to use `ptr` he same way as `arr` (i.e. want `ptr[x][y]` to have the same value as `arr[x][y]`) then your first approach is the correct one.